# Accessing web server running in android emulator from local machine

Tags: http, android-emulator, webserver, request

I m trying to access a web server running on android emulator from my machine. I know the reverse i.e how to access the server running on local machine from android emulator ( using 10.0.2.2) . I have searched a lot about this stuff but couldn't get any relevant information.

When the server is up and running inside the emulator I can access it using 10.0.2.15:portNumber. I can do a telnet to the emulator but I wonder how that will be helpful.
Any suggestions on how to get connect to web server running inside the emulator.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
adb forward tcp:[pcPort] tcp:[androidPort]
```